# Does $\chi(X) = \chi(Y)$ imply $H_p(X) \cong H_p(Y)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Does there exist spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that $\chi(X) = \chi(Y)$ such that there is (at least one) $p$ such that $H_p(X) \ncong H_p(Y)$? If so, what can we say about spaces with the same Euler characteristic with nonidentical $p$-th homology?

Comment: Have you tried any examples?

Comment: Clearly not enough as there are so many great examples below! I suspected the answer is yes. More interested in second question.

Comment: It would be truly amazing if a single number could completely determine the whole homology of a space...! :)

Answer (score 5):

The Euler characteristic is an extremely weak invariant: since it's the alternating sum of the ranks of the homology groups, there's a lot of cancellation possible in that sum, and so there's a lot of ways that two spaces can have the same Euler characteristic. For example, $S^1$ and $S^1 \times S^1$ have the same Euler characteristic ($0 = 1 - 1$ and $0 = 1 - 2 + 1$) but don't even have the same dimension, and also have different $H_1$ as well as different $H_2$. More generally, $S^1$ times any reasonable space (say a compact manifold) has Euler characteristic $0$.

Answer (score 4):

The Euler characteristic is multiplicative in the sense that if $M$ and $N$ are two spaces $\chi(M\times N) = \chi(M)\cdot\chi(N)$. Thus, if a space $M$ has Euler characteristic $0$ or $1$, this means that for any other space $N$ either $\chi(M\times N) = 0\cdot\chi(N)=0 = \chi(M)$, or $\chi(M\times N) = 1\cdot\chi(N) =\chi(N)$ holds, even though these spaces generally live in different dimensions.

An easy example to look at, is the circle $S^1$. It has Euler characteristic $0$, hence $(S^1)^n = S^1\times\ldots\times S^1$ has Euler characteristic $0$ as well, for any $n$. Does a circle have the same homology as the torus? In a similar vein, I'm sure you can cook up many more examples.

As for your last question, I don't think that one can say much in general about spaces with the same Euler characteristic, but non-identical homology groups.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Surfaces) on the subject you'll see there are some examples. For instance, if $T$ is the 2-torus, and $K$ the Klein bottle we have that,
$$
\chi(T) = \chi(K) =\chi(S^1) = 0.
$$
On the other hand, 
\begin{align}
H_1(T) &\simeq \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}, \\
H_1(K) &\simeq \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, \\
H_1(S^1) &\simeq \mathbb{Z}. \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Any closed odd-dimensional (real) manifold has Euler characteristic zero by [Poincaré duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_duality). A proof can be found after Corollary 3.37 in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*. There are many examples of odd-dimensional closed manifolds with differing homology of course. For instance, consider the odd-dimensional spheres $S^{2015}$ and $S^{2023}$.